# LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES attribute is 3

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, token

I'm trying to make a token from users credentials and then use `OpenService`. Here is my code:

```
logonSuccess = LogonUserW(userPartW, domainPartW, pwdW,
                                LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH,
                                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);

 PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES pPrivilegesToken = NULL;
 
 DWORD cbSize = 0;

  GetTokenInformation(token, TokenPrivileges, NULL, 0, &cbSize);

  pPrivilegesToken = (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) LocalAlloc(LPTR, cbSize);

  if (GetTokenInformation(token, TokenPrivileges, 
                               pPrivilegesToken, cbSize, &cbSize) == FALSE)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "GetTokenInformation:  cheijva %d.\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stderr);
  }

 char str[80] = {0};
 char str2[80] = {0};
 DWORD strsize = 80;
 DWORD str2size = 80;
 DWORD langid;

  for (int x = 0; x< pPrivilegesToken->PrivilegeCount; x++)
  {
    if (LookupPrivilegeName(NULL, &pPrivilegesToken->Privileges[x].Luid, str, &strsize) == 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "LookupPrivilegeName:  cheijva -> %d.\n", GetLastError());
      fflush(stderr);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "name -> %s\n", str);
    fprintf(stderr, "atributes -> %ld\n", pPrivilegesToken->Privileges[x].Attributes);
    fflush(stderr);
    if(LookupPrivilegeDisplayName (NULL, str, str2, &str2size, &langid) == 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "LookupPrivilegeName2222:  cheijva -> %d.\n", GetLastError());
      fflush(stderr);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "name -> %s\n", str2);
    fflush(stderr);
    strsize = str2size = 80;
  }
```

Please don't pay attention on styling and variable names and etc. My problem is that I have this output:

```
name -> SeShutdownPrivilege
atributes -> 3
name -> Shut down the system
name -> SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
atributes -> 3
name -> Bypass traverse checking
name -> SeUndockPrivilege
atributes -> 3
name -> Remove computer from docking station
name -> SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege
atributes -> 3
name -> Increase a process working set
name -> SeTimeZonePrivilege
atributes -> 3
name -> Change the time zone
```

As I know attribute indicates if privilege is enabled or not, I wanted to know what `3` means when it is set in `attributes` so I opened `wdm.h` and searched, But I found this

```
#define SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT (0x00000001L)
#define SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED            (0x00000002L)
#define SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED            (0X00000004L)
#define SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS    (0x80000000L)

#define SE_PRIVILEGE_VALID_ATTRIBUTES   (SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT | \
                                         SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED            | \
                                         SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED            | \
                                         SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS)
```

I could not find the value 3. Also I noticed that If I change `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH` in `LogonUser` to `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` I get this output

```
name -> SeShutdownPrivilege
atributes -> 0
name -> Shut down the system
name -> SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
atributes -> 3
name -> Bypass traverse checking
name -> SeUndockPrivilege
atributes -> 0
name -> Remove computer from docking station
name -> SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege
atributes -> 0
name -> Increase a process working set
name -> SeTimeZonePrivilege
atributes -> 0
name -> Change the time zone
```

Also when I'm using `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH` in `LogonUser` `OpenService` fails with error code 5, which means `ACCESS_DENIED`, as it doesn't have return value I can find the error,  but If I use `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` everything works fine. As I understand the problem is in privileges, as in both of the cases they are same it must be some problem enabling them(I want to make it work using BATCH, so my question is how to achieve it?). Sorry if my questions sounds silly I'm new with winapi and I know that this code won't help you to reproduce the problem but I thought someone might knew what the problem is. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: attributes this is flags. so 3 is `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT|SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED`

Comment: oh... yes... Thank you so much :) But if you know, could you also explain why one method works and another not?

Comment: sending SAS- what concrete function fail ?

Comment: Sorry for misuderstanding, I already edited the question, not sending SAS but `OpenService` fails, sorry again I had problems with it too and interupted with one another.

Comment: OpenService - which ? with which *dwDesiredAccess* ? and you need lookup not privileges but groups

Comment: service = OpenService(serviceManager, Name,
                            SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL);

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding but what do you mean in groups?

Comment: you need query not `TokenPrivileges` - this is unrelated to result of `OpenService` but `TokenGroups` and compare this with SD returned by `QueryServiceObjectSecurity`

Comment: thanks :) one more question Is it possible to get the privileges which are needed to open  service?

Comment: you not understand - for open service not need have any privileges.

Comment: So only SID in token is needed for that?

Comment: how i say checked is `TokenGroups` vs object security descriptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attributes this is flags. so 3 is `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT|SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED`

when thread try get access to some secured object (with associated [`SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379561(v=vs.85).aspx) in most case checked thread token groups vs [`SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379561(v=vs.85).aspx) *DACL* and [*mandatory integrity label*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648648(v=vs.85).aspx). however this is not always exactly - token privileges also used in this process - say if thread token(if thread not have token process token used) have `SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_PRIVILEGE` the `WRITE_OWNER` access is granted. some api can use another privileges (say `OpenProcess` look are `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` exist) but this is exceptions.

`SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL` usually (by default) granted to `SYSTEM`, `Administrators`,  `INTERACTIVE` and `SERVICE`

if user logon with `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH` he not member of `INTERACTIVE` group, when if user logon with `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` he will be member of `INTERACTIVE` group and have `SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL` granted.

if user fail get `SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL` access with `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH` - he is not member of `Administrators` groups (if default security on service used)

most notable different in `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` vs `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH`

interactive will be member of `INTERACTIVE` (*S-1-5-4*) group when batch member of `BATCH` (*S-1-5-3*) group.

also if user in "administrator" batch logon will be member of *S-1-5-32-544* `Administrators` and *S-1-5-114* `Local account and member of Administrators group` with `SE_GROUP_ENABLED` attribute. and also have *S-1-16-12288* `High Mandatory Level`

but with interactive logon user will be member of `Administrators` and `Local account and member of Administrators group` with `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY` - as result on practice not member of this groups. and also have `Medium Mandatory Level`

usual(default) service *DACL* is next

```
000F01FF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
000F01FF S-1-5-32-544 Administrators
0002018D S-1-5-4 INTERACTIVE
0002018D S-1-5-6 SERVICE
```

so again - in your case user obviously not member or Administrator group - as result in batch logon he fail open service with `SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL` (*0x100*) access (no `INTERACTIVE`, no `Administrators`) but interactive login (even for not admin user) have this access, because it granted to `INTERACTIVE` group and user member of this group with interactive logon

Comment: Thank you so much , This is the most complete answer of the question I have ever read :)

Answer (score 1):

3 is `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT|SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` (`1|2` == `3`).

The user logging on [needs SeBatchLogonRight](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2005/03/21/how-to-impersonate/) when using LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH.

Since you did not post the OpenService code it is hard to tell what is going on. Privileges are not used, you need to look at the service ACL:

> Before granting the requested access, the system checks the access token of the calling process against the discretionary access-control list of the security descriptor associated with the service object.

`OpenService(..., READ_CONTROL)` and then call [`QueryServiceObjectSecurity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379312(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the ACL.

`GetTokenInformation(..., TokenGroups, ...)` on your token will give you a list of SIDs, compare these against the SIDs in the service ACL to see which rights are granted. It is also possible to perform an [AccessCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374815(v=vs.85).aspx).